# Oracle APEX Cards Template with condition

Tags: oracle-apex

I 've built some action menu with cards template (base on classic report). I'm using 3 cards to redirect user to other pages in application. It's possible to configure some conditions for this cards? I need similar solution to authorization schema where some users will see only two cards, and some users with other authorization level can see the third card.

I've tried to use authorization schema just like in Classic report but it's not working.

Report query is base on simple sql:

```
select '' as CARD_TITLE
      , '' as CARD_INITIALS
      , '' as CARD_LINK
      , 1 as ORDER_
from TABEL_A
union all
select '' as CARD_TITLE
      , '' as CARD_INITIALS
      , '' as CARD_LINK
      , 2 as ORDER_
from TABEL_A
union all
select '' as CARD_TITLE
      , '' as CARD_INITIALS
      , '' as CARD_LINK
      , 3 as ORDER_
from TABEL_A
ORDER BY ORDER_;
```

APEX 19.1

Answer (score 0):

Authorization schemes in APEX are a component that enables/disables other components (pages/regions/buttons/items/columns/etc...) based on the users privileges. They are not suitable for striping data, but you could use a workaround by using page or application items that are based on the return value of an authorization scheme.

Example on the EMP/DEPT table. Use case is that a user who has the "Administrator" authorization can see all rows and other users can only see the rows where `JOB = 'CLERK'`.

- Create an page item to hold the value of the auth scheme. Let's use P1_IS_ADMINISTRATOR.
- Add a before header computation to this page item of type "Function Body" with source:

```
IF apex_authorization.is_authorized('Administrator') THEN
  RETURN 'YES';
ELSE
  RETURN 'No';
END IF;
```

- Modify the where clause of the report:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM emp 
 WHERE :P1_IS_ADMINISTRATOR = 'YES' OR
       job = 'CLERK'
```

Another use of this technique is to conditionally display column values. If users with Administrator authorization can see the everyone's salary and other users can only see salary of users with job 'CLERK' then it can be solved by using that page item in the select clause

```
SELECT empno
      ,ename
      ,job
      ,mgr
      ,hiredate
      ,CASE WHEN JOB = 'CLERK' THEN TO_CHAR(sal)
            WHEN :P1_IS_ADMINISTRATOR = 'YES' THEN TO_CHAR(sal)
            ELSE 'above your paygrade'
            END as sal
      ,comm
      ,deptno
  FROM emp;
```

- Note that when this is done in a report P1_IS_ADMINISTRATOR  needs to be set as attribute "Items to Submit"
- If you plan to use this technique in multiple pages it might be useful to use an application item and an application computation instead of page items and page computation. In that case make sure the processing point of the computation is after the processing point of the authorization to avoid unwanted results.

So... for your case, the query would become:

```
select '' as CARD_TITLE
      , '' as CARD_INITIALS
      , '' as CARD_LINK
      , 1 as ORDER_
from TABEL_A
union all
select '' as CARD_TITLE
      , '' as CARD_INITIALS
      , '' as CARD_LINK
      , 2 as ORDER_
from TABEL_A
union all
select '' as CARD_TITLE
      , '' as CARD_INITIALS
      , '' as CARD_LINK
      , 3 as ORDER_
from TABEL_A where :P1_IS_ADMINISTRATOR = 'YES'
ORDER BY ORDER_;
```

You could also use a list with card template instead of a report and put an authorization on the list entry - that is the way this was handled before there was a cards report.